AWS SSO - How SSO role can assume an IAM policy in a specific AWS account?
Suppose

a user X is managed in Azure AD and linked to an SSO role in AWS organization.
we want to give IAM policy to access DynamoDB in an AWS account A to the user X.

I created the IAM policy in the Account A.
How can attach the IAM policy to the SSO role for user X?

You set up roles and permissions in AWS Identity Center (AIC). AIC deploys whatever it needs to deploy to each account. If you're using old style IAM federation it's time to change to AIC.
